# How to correctly display 2 UITextFields in a custom cell through AutoLayouts?

Tags: ios, xcode6, autolayout

I have created a CustomCell class that subclasses UITableViewCell. I have tried using AutoLayout to correctly display both UITextFields within the cell but it always seems to get chopped off on the simulator no matter the constraints I apply. I need the UITextFields to be side by side.

I would like the first UITextField to take up 70% of the cell. I would like the second UITextField to take up the remaining space. I also have an accessory checkmark in the cell. Any ideas what constraints I should be applying?

Answer (score 0):

By pressing CMD on the keyboard select the 2 UITextField the select equal width constraint. Now select the constraint, go in the editor panel and in the multiplier field out your proportion like:1/2, 2/3 etc

Comment: After doing this, I get missing constraints errors for both the X and Y for both UITextField. I also get a warning for misplaced views where both UITextFields's expected value do not match their actual value. I tried using Storyboard's add Missing Constraint option but the first UITextField is still a misplaced view.

Comment: It seems that you are not placing constraint correctly, "add missing constraint" should not be used when you are doing a minimum of experienced editing on constraints. You dictate where and how many constraints should be placed, The important thing is they need just to be sufficient to place a view